# Qt: using one widget in several layouts

Tags: qt, widget

I have a QTabBar, and all tabs are supposed to have the same widget in them:

```
layout1->addWidget(w);
layout2->addWidget(w);
```

However calling `addWidget` the second time causes this widget to disappear in the first layout.

Is there any way to use one widget to insert it in several tabs?

Of course I can always create a new widget instance for every tab, but that takes extra time and memory.

Comment: What's your declaration for `layout1` and `layout2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way to use one widget to insert it in several tabs?

No. If you want the widget to be seen twice, then you need two instances of it.

> Of course I can always create a new widget instance for every tab, but that takes extra time and memory.

Simple widgets are relatively cheap in regards to memory/time to create. Unless your GUI is becoming unresponsive and your profiler says that this is a problem, you are likely attempting a premature optimization.

Depending on the specific goal you're trying to accomplish, there are patterns such as using multiple views that share a single model that can potentially be employed.